# Pre-installed operating system re-installation

Tags: windows-8, toshiba-laptop

I bought a Toshiba Laptop (Intel i7) with Windows 8. Unfortunately I formatted the hard disk. How can I reinstall the original Windows 8?  I.e. The one which was in my system. Where can I download the pre installed windows 8?

Comment: did you really just format your c: partition? Or did create/delete partitions too? Toshiba usually has a hidden partition that contains the OS allowing you to reinstall.

Comment: "Press and hold the 0 (zero) key" on startup/reboot ... willget you into recovery. I think :)

Answer (score 3):

Logman's comment is correct for Toshiba laptops, it will boot into its hidden recovery partition. Hold down the zero key and press the power button, it should get you there. That will allow the OS to be reinstalled again, provided you did not format the whole drive after deleting partitions??
If you just formatted c drive only, there should be no issue, the hidden drive is still intact.